# Check if any select boxes have not been selected

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic number of select elements. When the form is submitted, I want to check if any of them have not been selected yet ie the `value == ""`, if so throw an error, any ideas how I do this please in Jquery? Thanks!

```
<div class="container-seller-commission">
  <div class="row-seller-commission">
    <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="4" selected="selected">Agent</option>
      <option value="2">Crisalix Global</option>
      <option value="1">Owner</option>
      <option value="3">Support</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row-seller-commission">
  <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="4" disabled="disabled">Agent</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Crisalix Global</option>
    <option value="1">Owner</option>
    <option value="3">Support</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="row-seller-commission">
  <select name="seller" id="seller" class="select-seller valid">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="4" disabled="disabled">Agent</option>
    <option value="2">Crisalix Global</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Owner</option>
    <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Support</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your jquery code?

Comment: You open 4 divs and closes 5. So you ave one `</div>` too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Here is the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obd6xasL/2/)**

And here is the code used in the Fiddle,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#validateButtonId").on("click",function(){

    var selectBoxFlag = true;

    //iterating through all the select boxes with class 'select-seller'
    $(".select-seller").each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ""){
        selectBoxFlag = false;
      }
    });

    if(selectBoxFlag){
        $("#formId").submit();
    }else{
        alert("Selectbox value is not selected!");
    }

  });
});
```

The "validateButtonId" is the ID of the button that you use when you try to submit the form, keep in mind that the `input type` of this button should be `button` and not `submit`

Answer (score 0):

Select all your selectboxes using `$('.select-seller')`, and then you can loop through all the boxes using the jquery-function `each()`. Inside the loop you can then get the value by using `$(this).val()` and compare it to an empty string. Then all you have to do is to keep track if atleast one box is missing a selection:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var unselected = false;
    $('.select-seller').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        unselected = true;
      }
    });
    if (unselected) {
        //Atleast one box is missing a selection
    } else {
        //All boxes has a selection
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/27333/)**.

On submit check all the select :

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var empty_select = false;

  $('select').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==''){
      empty_select = true
    }
  })

  if(empty_select)
    alert('Fill all selects')
  else
    alert('submit')
})
```